# Нужна ли запятая на стыке союзов перед тире?

Tags: запятые, тире, союзы

*Это нежелательно делать, но(,) если хочется(,) — можно.*

Здесь тире заменяет слово "то", насколько я могу судить. В связи с этим вопрос: применяется ли в этом случае правило о второй части двойного союза ("то", "но", "так")? Чувствуется, что запятые не нужны, но у Розенталя, например, насчёт тире ничего не говорится.

Comment: Говорится у него, есть там такое. Про "стык союзов" смотрите.

Comment: "Таким образом, при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза то, так или но, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и не ставится, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза".

Comment: Там не говорится именно о тире. В примерах подобных предложений тоже нет.

Comment: Есть там такой пример. Может, в соседнем параграфе. И, кстати, не раз об этом спрашивали, даже недавно было.

Comment: Вот: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Рассмотрим СПП с придаточным условия **из [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)**:

*Буде (= если) кто спросит о чём — **молчи*** (П.)

При двойном союзе в таком предложении ставится **запятая**, а не тире:

*Если кто спросит о чём, **то молчи.***

Отсюда ясна связь между **тире и местоимением ТО:** мы используем или двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, или тире.

2. Решение задачи:

*Это нежелательно делать, но **если хочется — можно.***

*Это нежелательно делать, но **если хочется, то можно.***

Comment: Не надо использовать устаревшие слова!